# Accessing multiple wifi networks simultaneously from debian wheezy

Tags: debian, wifi

I have got 2 wireless adapters on my machine (one built-in and the other a purchased USB wireless adapter)
is there a way I can utilize different WiFi networks simultaneously?

I have in mind something like having 2 workspaces on gnome3 each connected to a separate network or something similar to that.

Comment: Connecting to different networks works in the same as connecting to a single network, there's nothing special about it. But since you can have only one default route you have to set up your routing table. Even though it's possible to change the routing depending on which workspace is visible, I don't know what you want to achive and I doubt that the result will be practical.

Comment: @Marco: You can have multiple default routes using multiple routing tables, or multiple network namespaces, the latter being simpler to use in his case as no apps need to be configured. However, network namespaces are not integrated in gnome3, and they require root access anyway.

Comment: @BatchyX I didn't know that's supported. Thanks for putting me straight on this.